# Sheets formula to display all quotients and remainders of X divided by Y

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need a formula that outputs the result below shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried a combination of `QUOTIENT()` and `MOD()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something in the style of:

```
={sequence(QUOTIENT(A2,C2),1,C2,0);mod(A2,C2)}
```

[image]